# How to catch the url that cause SSL certificate_verify_failed in python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, httplib2, pygsheets

I'm trying to access the google sheets api with python within corporate network, that uses firewall.  Then, I need to discover all the url/domains google sheets api requests to send IT team unlock the access for theses url's.

I am using the pygsheets library for connect with google api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for users on your network to access Google Drive and Google Docs editors, your firewall rules should connect to the following hosts and ports. Otherwise, users may be blocked or denied access from these services.

For the following hosts, [N] means any single decimal digit and * means any string not containing a period.

Oauth server

- accounts.google.com:443/HTTPS

API stuff

- apis.google.com:443/HTTPS
- *.clients[N].google.com:443/HTTPS
- *.googleapis.com:443/HTTPS
- script.google.com:443/HTTPS

Other

- www.google.com:443/HTTPS
- googledrive.com:443/HTTPS
- drive.google.com:443/HTTPS
- *.drive.google.com:443/HTTPS
- docs.google.com:443/HTTPS
- *.docs.google.com:443/HTTPS
- *.c.docs.google.com:443/HTTPS
- sheets.google.com:443/HTTPS
- slides.google.com:443/HTTPS
- talk.google.com:5222/XMPP (needed only for Backup and Sync or the legacy - version, Drive for Mac/PC)
- takeout.google.com:443/HTTPS
- gg.google.com:443/HTTPS
- ssl.google-analytics.com:443/HTTPS
- video.google.com:443/HTTPS
- s.ytimg.com:443/HTTPS
- *.googleusercontent.com:443/HTTPS
- *.gstatic.com:443/HTTPS
- lh[N].google.com:443/HTTPS
- [N].client-channel.google.com:443/HTTPS
- clients[N].google.com:443/HTTPS

Ripped from [Google Drive firewall and proxy settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2589954?hl=en)

Some of theses are for google drive the web application and others are for google drive api, sheets api and the oauth servers.   I could probably wittle it down a little but wasnt sure if you wanted that.  It may be best that they just open most of them and go from there.

Comment: Great, @DalmTo ! Thanks you!
May you describe only the google drive api, sheets api and the oauth servers?

Comment: Yes I can pick them appart and give you an idea which one's to start with.     maybe tommorow I am mobile right now

Comment: There's an educated guess.