# What firewall and proxy settings are needed to be opened in order for google calendar api for nodejs to be working?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I have searches for internet, but I am not sure:

I am using google calendar api in NodeJS. I use only fetching calendars list and fetching all available events list for particular calendar. Security teem is asking me exact destinations in internet that are needed to be opened in order for google calendar api to be working.

What are these destinations?

P.S. If additional info are needed please, let me know.

Thank you

Comment: @DaImTo It is assumed that I have internet access isn't it? Because well . . . everybody knows that to access web api you need internet? I am asking list of internet destinations, because security team does not want  to make our server available publicly on internet. They want to give access only to certain destinations. i am no sure: what are these destinations for google calendar api? Thanks

Comment: Are we talking Firewall or proxy issues here?

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for your time. Issue is following: our server currently is granted full internet access and our NodeJS with calendar api is working fine. Security team does not want this "full internet access", they want particular web destinations that they will grant access to. I was unable to find information on internet: What destinations are needed to be accessible from our server in order calendar api to be accessible? maybe its just https://www.google.com? I am just lost :( Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/50252843/1841839

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about FireWall settings or proxy settings.  I think you should have a look at this page [Drive and Sites firewall and proxy settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2589954?hl=en)  There used to be a better page but the last time i looked for it was probably fie years ago.

This is the full list

```
www.google.com:443/HTTPS
accounts.google.com:443/HTTPS
googledrive.com:443/HTTPS
drive.google.com:443/HTTPS
*.drive.google.com:443/HTTPS
docs.google.com:443/HTTPS
*.docs.google.com:443/HTTPS
*.c.docs.google.com:443/HTTPS
sheets.google.com:443/HTTPS
slides.google.com:443/HTTPS
talk.google.com:5222/XMPP (needed only for Backup and Sync)
takeout.google.com:443/HTTPS
gg.google.com:443/HTTPS
script.google.com:443/HTTPS
ssl.google-analytics.com:443/HTTPS
video.google.com:443/HTTPS
s.ytimg.com:443/HTTPS
apis.google.com:443/HTTPS
*.clients[N].google.com:443/HTTPS
*.googleapis.com:443/HTTPS
*.googleusercontent.com:443/HTTPS
*.gstatic.com:443/HTTPS
*.gvt1.com:443/HTTPS
lh[N].google.com:443/HTTPS
[N].client-channel.google.com:443/HTTPS
clients[N].google.com:443/HTTPS
inputtools.google.com:443/HTTPS
sites.google.com:443/HTTPS
sites.google.com:80/HTTP
sites.google.com:443/HTTPS
*.sites.google.com:443/HTTPS
*.googlegroups.com:443/HTTPS
ipv4.google.com:443/HTTPS
ipv4.google.com:80/HTTP
```

I don't known if you need them all but your going to defiantly need these.

- googleapis.com:443/HTTPS
- accounts.google.com:443/HTTPS

Comment: I answered this same question a few years ago https://stackoverflow.com/a/50252843/1841839

Comment: Useful information!

Comment: I would give them the load link as well.   Past me did some research on it for a client.  Its a bit different as your going with calendar.   You probably dont need all the docs stuff.