# IP address range of Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am developing an application on Google Cloud Platform that uses the Google Analytics (v3) API. Due to security constraints, all traffic has to go through a firewall (in a VPC).

As a result, I need a comprehensive list of IP ranges used by the servers of Google Analytics API, which I could reliably use in firewall rules. Where can I find this list?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you should just use the generic google apis list. You probably wont need all of them but its a start  I have two answers over the years that contain the list https://stackoverflow.com/a/50252843/1841839    https://stackoverflow.com/a/71524284/1841839   If you want i can try and pick though some to give you a start

Comment: Thanks for the reply! On the link you provided there are hostnames, but I don't think you can use hostnames in a firewall rule in GCP, you can only have IP addresses...

Comment: Thats new to me.  ping them you should get an ip back but its not going to help you if they change the ips.

Answer (score 2):

This should be ample: https://support.google.com/a/answer/10026322?hl=en

Google exposes the ranges here: https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json

And here are google cloud ranges: https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json

Check if your endopint's IP is in there. I checked a few API endpoints IPs and they were in the first list for me.

Answer (score 0):

On top of BNazaruk's links, there's also the same list available in plain text format, at

https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt